# How to filter an object array based on the contents of child array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this data

```
var data = [
  {
    title: "App development summary",
    category: [],
  },
  {
    title: "to experiment 2",
    category: [],
  },
  {
    title: "Some of these books I have read",
    category: [
      {
        _id: "5f7c99faab20d14196f2062e",
        name: "books",
      },
      {
        _id: "5f7c99faab20d14196f2062f",
        name: "to read",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Quora users and snippets",
    category: [
      {
        _id: "5f7c99feab20d14196f20631",
        name: "quora",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Politics to research",
    category: [
      {
        _id: "5f7c9a02ab20d14196f20633",
        name: "politics",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Say I want to get all the entries with the category of `books`. I tried doing this:

```
var bookCat = data.map(note => {
 return note.category.map(cat => {
   if(cat.name === "books" ) return note
 })
})
```

But the result comes back with some empty and undefined arrays.

I was able to filter the empty arrays (at one point) but not the undefined

[image]

**Edit**

In plain English "if the object ha category.name "books", give me the title"

Comment: Do you want the `name: "to read",` object to be included?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, that's part of the categories. I'm trying to get the book that has the category of 'book' the fact that it also has the category 'to read' doesn't matter.

Comment: Please show an example of the results you expect to receive

Comment: @Phil the result from the above would be `data[2]` that's the only object with the category of `book`. I misread the answer given. the code actually works but doesn't loop. If there was another object like `data[2]` the code provided in the first answer would not show it. this https://jsbin.com/popibedugu/edit?js,console selects the right one but leaves out the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by whether the array's `category` contains at least one `name` which is `books`:

```js
var data=[{title:"App development summary",category:[]},{title:"to experiment 2",category:[]},{title:"Some of these books I have read",category:[{_id:"5f7c99faab20d14196f2062e",name:"books"},{_id:"5f7c99faab20d14196f2062f",name:"to read"}]},{title:"Quora users and snippets",category:[{_id:"5f7c99feab20d14196f20631",name:"quora"}]},{title:"Politics to research",category:[{_id:"5f7c9a02ab20d14196f20633",name:"politics"}]}];

const output = data
  .filter(item => item.category.some(
    ({ name }) => name === 'books'
  ));
console.log(output);
```

If there's guaranteed to be only a single matching object, use `.find` instead:

```js
var data=[{title:"App development summary",category:[]},{title:"to experiment 2",category:[]},{title:"Some of these books I have read",category:[{_id:"5f7c99faab20d14196f2062e",name:"books"},{_id:"5f7c99faab20d14196f2062f",name:"to read"}]},{title:"Quora users and snippets",category:[{_id:"5f7c99feab20d14196f20631",name:"quora"}]},{title:"Politics to research",category:[{_id:"5f7c9a02ab20d14196f20633",name:"politics"}]}];

const output = data
  .find(item => item.category.some(
    ({ name }) => name === 'books'
  ));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the entire parent of the category

Comment: In plain English "if the object ha category.name "books", give me the title". That's what I'm having trouble with, getting the parent array the moment I've filtered the category name.

Comment: Sorry again, what if there are two objects with the category 'books'. https://jsbin.com/popibedugu/edit?js,console I added another entry and doesn't show

Comment: @relidon It looks to work? It shows a result array of length 2 - both objects with a `books` get included